How can I activate the "Disable permission monitoring" option on my Motorola Moto G23?
I just want to know a way to activate the "Disable permission monitoring" option on my Motorola Moto G23 so that I no longer have problems with my mouse (otherwise, the right click does not work).
If that option does not exist, can you recommend other alternatives?

Welcome. This looks like XY-problem where you're trying to "fix the mouse right-click" by "activating 'Disable permission monitoring'", which might or might not be the solution. That said, googling the option hints at Developer options, which can be enabled by going to Settings - About phone - tapping Build number 7 times. However, looks like the option is not available on every device (Google Pixel 3a on Android 12 doesn't have this). Curious, from where did you get this information?
